# After losing ssh connection to box with tmux running, shell is garbled

Tags: bash, tmux

I have tmux running on a box I ssh into. From my tmux session, I have various panes and ssh connections open to other boxes.

When I lose my ssh to the box with tmux running, I often see garbled text when I try to type anything. `command not found` repeatedly outputs with huge spacing between. Is there a fix for this?

```
$ -bash: 0: command not found
-bash: 71: command not found
-bash: 10M0: command not found
-bash: 71: command not found
-bash: 10m: command not found
```

I have to close my terminal emulator at this point, or at least the iterm tab running the shell.

Comment: can you run the command `reset` (this command will reinitialize the terminal)?

Comment: What application were you running over SSH? It looks like the application left the terminal in a strange mode, but I don't recognize it. It would help a lot if you told us what action triggers each of those messages.

Comment: Waiting for this to happen again through a disconnect when I leave work. Each line output is from pressing any key on the keyboard

Comment: @blissini, that works!